# API not getting parameters from HttpClient

Tags: c#, angular, rxjs

I am not sure why I can't pass data from the body to my API?

Below is the enclosed code.  In debug the API patch method does get hit but all the properties are empty/null.

I can verify that the API works by using Fiddler.  So I must be missing something with the Angular HttpClient.

API:

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]MyParameters parameters)
{
// Do Stuff
}
```

MyParameters

```
public class MyParameters
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Value { get; set; }

    }
```

Typescript

```
headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json");

  updateItem(myItem: MyItem) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(myItem);
    console.log(body);

    return this.http      
      .patch(this.ApiUri,
        {
          "Id": myItem.Id,
          "Name": myItem.Name,
          "Value": myItem.Value
        }, { headers: this.headers })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  };
```

Comment: @xxbbcc Because the first two blocks of code are C#...

Comment: If you check in the browser's developer tools network panel when you send the request, is the data being sent successfully, or is it null / empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who encounters the same issue.  I was able to resolve it by this:

```
    let body = JSON.stringify(myItem);

    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
      };

    return this.http      
      .patch(this.ApiUri, body, options)  
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers:headers });


return this.http      
      .patch(this.ApiUri,
        {
          "Id": myItem.Id,
          "Name": myItem.Name,
          "Value": myItem.Value
        }, options)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: In what way is this different than OPs code? You can't just dump code in an answer without explanation.

Comment: It appears that he has is utilizing the RequestOptions however I get Typscript errors trying to mimic his code.